# Syntax error in query using ltree on Postgresql 9.6.5

Tags: sql, postgresql, ltree

I have a problem with ltree extension on Postgresql 9.6.5

I have a table called category with the following DDL (I simplified it a bit):

```
CREATE TABLE dictionary.category
(
    id serial not null constraint category_pkey primary key,
    name text not null,
    parent_id integer constraint category_parent_id_fkey references dictionary.category
);
```

After creation of ltree extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION ltree;
```

I'm trying to make some query e.g.:

```
SELECT id, text2ltree(name) FROM dictionary.category;
```

or

```
SELECT id, name::ltree FROM dictionary.category;
```

or escaping column name

```
SELECT id, text2ltree("name") FROM dictionary.category;
```

And it gives me:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at position 12
```

all the time

But when I try:

```
SELECT id, text2ltree('a.b.v') FROM dictionary.category;
```

or

```
SELECT id, text2ltree(id::text) FROM dictionary.category
```

it gives me correct results.

I suppose it is related to the fact that **name** is a reserved keyword. But why escaping do not work? Also I trie to rename a column to something like **abcd** it gives me syntax error anyway.

Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question. It appears that those error message is not related to a query itself. It is related to a text that can by contained in ltree path. It appears that l tree path allows only alfanumeric characters and nothing more.

```
SELECT id, text2ltree(regexp_replace(name, '[^[:alpha:]]', '', 'g')) FROM dictionary.category;
```

returns correct results.

Anyway, the error message is very misleading.

Comment: agreed about the error message being misleading.  It persists in postgresql version 11.x

Comment: One minor clarification, ltree supports both alpha and digits, so the regex can be - `[^[:alpha:][:digit:]]`

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. We use `extract(epoch FROM date_start)` to generate a LTREE from a date column, but one of our records returns a negative number.

[PostgreSQL Date/Time Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-datetime.html)
**epoch**
For timestamp with time zone values, the number of seconds ***since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC*** (can be negative); for date and timestamp values, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 local time; for interval values, the total number of seconds in the interval